# Woocommerce filter add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price') doesn't apply via ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Role Based Pricing for WooCommerce plugin to get prices variations according to the user role.

When I call the functions to get products the filter is applied correctly, but when I make the call the the function via ajax it always gives the default price value.

```
function get_products_from_category($quantity=12,$page=1,$cat=[]){

  $desiredPost = queryToGetProductsAccordingTofilters($quantity,$page,$cat);
  $list = [];
  foreach ($desiredPost as $key => $value) {
    $myproduct = wc_get_product($value->ID);
    $list[] = [
      (...)
      'price' => $myproduct->get_price().get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(),
    ];
  }
  return $list;
}
```

If I call the function normaly in the archive-product, header, footer the filter price is always used, via ajax returns the normal value.

Already tried to force the plugin load inside the function

```
require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/role-based-pricing-for-woocommerce/addify_role_based_pricing.php';
```

The function is call by:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_getshopproducts', 'my_getshopproducts'); add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_getshopproducts', 'my_getshopproducts'); function my_getshopproducts(){ 
//get values from POST, $quantity,$page,$cat
$values = get_products_from_category($quantity,$page,$cat);
echo $json_encode($values);
}
```

Again, if I call

```
get_products_from_category($quantity,$page,$cat)
```

directly without being from an ajax call the correct price is given (add_filter is being applied).

checked if the plugins are loaded but can't find why this is happening, I guess for some reason the filter is not been applied?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is most likely about the way the parameters are handled. If it is an ajax call you need to capture the $cat variable differently.

You didn't post your JS, but I'm assuming it looks something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {
          action: 'get_products_from_category',
          quantity: quantity,
          page: page,
          cat: cat

        },
        success: function (response) {
        //Do Stuff
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
          console.log(errorThrown);
        }
      });
```

In which case you'll need to get the variables from the $_POST.

```
function get_products_from_category($quantity=12,$page=1,$cat=[]){

  if(wp_doing_ajax()){
     if(isset($_POST['quantity'])){
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity']; 
     }
     if(isset($_POST['page'])){
        $page = $_POST['page']; 
     }
     if(isset($_POST['cat'])){
        $cat = $_POST['cat']; 
     }
  }

  $desiredPost = queryToGetProductsAccordingTofilters($quantity,$page,$cat);
  $list = [];
  foreach ($desiredPost as $key => $value) {
    $myproduct = wc_get_product($value->ID);
    $list[] = [
      (...)
      'price' => $myproduct->get_price().get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(),
    ];
  }
  return $list;
}
```

Comment: My problem is not getting the variables from the post, I'm getting them correctly, the problem is the filter for the price not being applied when call from the ajax call.

The function is called from a ajax action. 

    add_action('wp_ajax_my_getshopproducts', 'my_getshopproducts');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_getshopproducts', 'my_getshopproducts');
    function my_getshopproducts(){
     //get values from POST
    //call get_products_from_category
    }

Comment: You need to post the relevant code about how you're trying to use the ajax call.

Comment: that is not relevant to my question... The ajax call works fine, the add_filter is not being applied. but I will add it.